# Calculate transaction items total's and transaction item with mongoose query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

In mongoose, I have a collection for transactions. Each transaction has a list of Items Something like this:

```
var transactionItemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    productId: String,
    quantity: Number,
    price: Number
});

var transactionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    details: String,
    items: [transactionItemSchema ],
}, {
    timestamps: true
});
```

I need to calculate each item total's value by multiplying price * quantity and rounding 2 decimals, but also I need to get the transaction total by summing all item total's in a transaction. So for example if I have this transactions in mongo:

```
[{
  details: 'First Transaction',
  items: [{
      price: 5.2,
      quantity: 2
    }, {
      price: 4,
      quantity: 3
    }]
  }, {
  details: 'First Transaction',
  items: [{
      price: 0.333,
      quantity: 3
    }]
  }]
```

return something like this when pulling transactions:

```
[{
  total: 22.40,
  details: 'First Transaction',
  items: [{
    price: 5.2,
    quantity: 2,
    total: 10.40
  }, {
    price: 4,
    quantity: 3,
    total: 12.00
  }]
}, {
  total: 1.00,
  details: 'Second Transaction',
  items: [{
    price: 0.333,
    quantity: 3,
    total: 1.00
  }]
}]
```

Is there a way we can achieve this with some aggregations with mongoose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) and [`$multiply`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/multiply/) here.

Assuming the model is calls `Transaction`:

```
Transaction.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "items": {
      "$map": {
        "input": "$items",
        "in": {
          "$mergeObjects": [
            "$$this",
            { "total": { "$round": [{ "$multiply": [ "$$this.price", "$$this.quantity" ] }, 2] } }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Or without [`$mergeObjects`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/):

```
Transaction.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "total": {
      "$sum": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$items",
          "in": {
            "$round": [{ "$multiply": [ "$$this.price", "$$this.quantity" ] }, 2]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "items": {
      "$map": {
        "input": "$items",
        "in": {
          "price": "$$this.price",
          "quantity": "$$this.quantity",
          "total": { "$round": [{ "$multiply": [ "$$this.price", "$$this.quantity" ] }, 2] }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

The [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) operator is essentially used for *array transforms*, in which you provide an array of `input` and an expression to apply to each array element which defines the object output for each element. Here [`$multiply`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/multiply/) is applied with the two arguments to "multiply" for a result.

The [`$mergeObjects`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/) is *optionally* used as a way to take the existing object properties for each element ( `price` and `quantity` ) and include them in the output object. The alternative is to manually specify the properties in the output objects for each element, just as shown.

Of course for the *document total* the same is essentially supplied, but just returning a single value and feeding that to the [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) operator in order to "total" the results

All of that said, there's nothing wrong with simply manipulating the result *post* return from the server:

```
let results = await Transaction.find().lean();

// Then manipulate the items arrays

results = results.map(r =>
  ({
    ...r,
    total: r.items.reduce((o, i) =>
       o + parseFloat((i.price * i.quantity).toFixed(2)), 0),
    items: r.items.map(i =>
      ({ ...i, total: parseFloat((i.price * i.quantity).toFixed(2)) })
    )
  })
);
```

Simply note the use of [`lean()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#query_Query-lean) here, which returns plain JavaScript objects rather than Mongoose Documents and thus allows you to manipulate the structure of the returned results.

---

Here's a full listing of both approaches:

```
const { Schema } = mongoose = require('mongoose');

const uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';
const opts = { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true };

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

mongoose.set('debug', true);
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);

const transactionItemSchema = new Schema({
  productId: String,
  quantity: Number,
  price: Number
});

const transactionSchema = new Schema({
  details: String,
  items: [transactionItemSchema]
},{
  timestamps: true
});

const Transaction = mongoose.model('Transaction', transactionSchema);


const initialData = [
  {
    details: 'First Transaction',
    items: [
      { price: 5.2, quantity: 2 },
      { price: 4, quantity: 3 }
    ]
  },
  {
    details: 'Second Transaction',
    items: [
      { price: 0.333, quantity: 3 }
    ]
  }
];

const log = data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2));

(async function() {

  try {
    const conn = await mongoose.connect(uri, opts);

    // Clean data
    await Promise.all(
      Object.values(conn.models).map(m => m.deleteMany())
    );

    await Transaction.insertMany(initialData);

    // Aggregate example

    let result1 = await Transaction.aggregate([
      { "$addFields": {
        "total": {
          "$sum": {
            "$map": {
              "input": "$items",
              "in": {
                "$round": [
                  { "$multiply": [ "$$this.price", "$$this.quantity" ] },
                  2
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "items": {
          "$map": {
            "input": "$items",
            "in": {
              "$mergeObjects": [
                "$$this",
                { "total": {
                  "$round": [
                    { "$multiply": [ "$$this.price", "$$this.quantity" ] },
                    2
                  ]
                }}
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }}
    ]);

    log({ result1 });


    // Plain JavaScript example

    let result2 = await Transaction.find().lean();

    result2 = result2.map(r =>
      ({
        ...r,
        total: r.items.reduce((o, i) =>
           o + parseFloat((i.price * i.quantity).toFixed(2)), 0),
        items: r.items.map(i =>
          ({ ...i, total: parseFloat((i.price * i.quantity).toFixed(2)) })
        )
      })
    );

    log({ result2 });

  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  } finally {
    mongoose.disconnect();
  }


})();
```

And the output:

```
Mongoose: transactions.deleteMany({}, {})
Mongoose: transactions.insertMany([ { _id: 5d8f4dfcaf9f6a2f8ec28039, details: 'First Transaction', items: [ { _id: 5d8f4dfcaf9f6a2f8ec2803b, price: 5.2, quantity: 2 }, { _id: 5d8f4dfcaf9f6a2f8ec2803a, price: 4, quantity: 3 } ], __v: 0, createdAt: 2019-09-28T12:11:40.060Z, updatedAt: 2019-09-28T12:11:40.061Z }, { _id: 5d8f4dfcaf9f6a2f8ec2803c, details: 'Second Transaction', items: [ { _id: 5d8f4dfcaf9f6a2f8ec2803d, price: 0.333, quantity: 3 } ], __v: 0, createdAt: 2019-09-28T12:11:40.062Z, updatedAt: 2019-09-28T12:11:40.062Z } ], {})
Mongoose: transactions.aggregate([ { '$addFields': { total: { '$sum': { '$map': { input: '$items', in: { '$round': [ { '$multiply': [ '$$this.price', '$$this.quantity' ] }, 2 ] } } } }, items: { '$map': { input: '$items', in: { '$mergeObjects': [ '$$this', { total: { '$round': [ { '$multiply': [Array] }, 2 ] } } ] } } } } } ], {})
{
  "result1": [
    {
      "_id": "5d8f4dfcaf9f6a2f8ec28039",
      "details": "First Transaction",
      "items": [
        {
          "_id": "5d8f4dfcaf9f6a2f8ec2803b",
          "price": 5.2,
          "quantity": 2,
          "total": 10.4
        },
        {
          "_id": "5d8f4dfcaf9f6a2f8ec2803a",
          "price": 4,
          "quantity": 3,
          "total": 12
        }
      ],
      "__v": 0,
      "createdAt": "2019-09-28T12:11:40.060Z",
      "updatedAt": "2019-09-28T12:11:40.061Z",
      "total": 22.4
    },
    {
      "_id": "5d8f4dfcaf9f6a2f8ec2803c",
      "details": "Second Transaction",
      "items": [
        {
          "_id": "5d8f4dfcaf9f6a2f8ec2803d",
          "price": 0.333,
          "quantity": 3,
          "total": 1
        }
      ],
      "__v": 0,
      "createdAt": "2019-09-28T12:11:40.062Z",
      "updatedAt": "2019-09-28T12:11:40.062Z",
      "total": 1
    }
  ]
}
Mongoose: transactions.find({}, { projection: {} })
{
  "result2": [
    {
      "_id": "5d8f4dfcaf9f6a2f8ec28039",
      "details": "First Transaction",
      "items": [
        {
          "_id": "5d8f4dfcaf9f6a2f8ec2803b",
          "price": 5.2,
          "quantity": 2,
          "total": 10.4
        },
        {
          "_id": "5d8f4dfcaf9f6a2f8ec2803a",
          "price": 4,
          "quantity": 3,
          "total": 12
        }
      ],
      "__v": 0,
      "createdAt": "2019-09-28T12:11:40.060Z",
      "updatedAt": "2019-09-28T12:11:40.061Z",
      "total": 22.4
    },
    {
      "_id": "5d8f4dfcaf9f6a2f8ec2803c",
      "details": "Second Transaction",
      "items": [
        {
          "_id": "5d8f4dfcaf9f6a2f8ec2803d",
          "price": 0.333,
          "quantity": 3,
          "total": 1
        }
      ],
      "__v": 0,
      "createdAt": "2019-09-28T12:11:40.062Z",
      "updatedAt": "2019-09-28T12:11:40.062Z",
      "total": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Neil Lunn, I would like to go for the mongoose option for learning purpouses, do you know if there is a  "round" operator for each multiply in mongo and how we could also get the transaction final total by summing up each item total calculated value?

Comment: @GiovaniiMirkoTerrazas Yes there is `$round`, as well as using `toFixed()` with JavaScript. Added to examples.

Comment: Thanks for the update @NeilLunn I think is missing the part of summing up each transaction item total and create a new total value per transaciton object. For example for the first transaction should be (22.40 = 10.40 +12.00)

Comment: I fixed by adding this piece of code: ````{
                $addFields: {
                    total: {
                        $sum: {
                            $map: { input: "$items", as: "item", in: "$$item.total" }
                        }
                    }
                },
            }````           Could you update the answer if you aggre so I can accept the answer? thanks

Comment: @GiovaniiMirkoTerrazas My bad, I must have missed that in your question. Added examples into the answer including that as well now. You don't actually need an additional stage either.

Comment: Just a note with $round that just works with mongo 4.2 and up

Comment: @GiovaniiMirkoTerrazas. Fair. If need be I could always include an example using `$mod`, but there should also be existing answers which show how to "round" with previous MongoDB versions and usage of a modulo